# mimetools.Message() to python 3 email.message.Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I try to port a python 2.x code to python 3.
The line im struggeling with is

```
from mimetools import Message
...
headers = Message(StringIO(data.split('\r\n', 1)[1]))
```

i have figured out that mimetools are no longer present in python 3 and that the replacement is the email class.
I tried out to replace it like this:

```
headers = email.message_from_file(io.StringIO(data.split('\r\n', 1)[1]))
```

but with that i get this error:

```
    headers = email.message_from_file(io.StringIO(data.split('\r\n', 1)[1]))
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

i am searching for an hint to do this porting from mimetools to email correct.
The original code is not from me. It can be found here :
https://gist.github.com/jkp/3136208

Comment: solved..

    import email
    ...
    stream = io.StringIO()
    rxString = data.decode("utf-8").split('\r\n', 1)[1]
    stream.write(rxString)
    headers = email.message_from_string(rxString)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex's own solution from his comment:

```
import email
stream = io.StringIO() 
rxString = data.decode("utf-8").split('\r\n', 1)[1]
stream.write(rxString) 
headers = email.message_from_string(rxString)
```

Answer (score 1):

found short solution

```python
from email import message_from_string    
data = socket.recv(4096)
headers = message_from_string(str(data, 'ASCII').split('\r\n', 1)[1])
```